# Asynk task doesnt execute doinBackground

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask, dialog, progressdialog

After the help of many people, i got this code: but im facing two problems 1 - Seems that thread sleep only affects the thread not the message in progress dialog, so Tarea finalizada cant be seen as appear and disappear so quickly. If i set a message of Tarea inicializada ( begining task) it cant be shown...if i put in background it doesnt show, and if i put it after "Cargando datos por favor espere" ( loading data please wait) it shows Tarea inicializada but not Cargando datos. I need some trick to view the different messages...

Ideally would be:
- "Cargando datos por favor espere" ( two seconds)
- Tarea inicializada ( two seconds)
- Tarea finalizada ( two seconds).
- Dismiss and return to main activity

Thanks again

class ServicioInicial extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void> {
private Context mContext;

```
ProgressDialog mProgress;
private ServicioInicialFinalizado mCallback;

public ServicioInicial( Context context) {
    this.mContext=context;
    this.mCallback= ( ServicioInicialFinalizado) context;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgress= new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mProgress.setMessage("Cargando contactos...Por favor espere");
    mProgress.show();
   // mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea comenzada");

}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... resultado) {


    try 
    {
        //Aqui simulo un calculo supercomplicado y lo ralentizamos  a 500 ms por numero


          // mProgress.setMessage("Tarea comenzada");

            //Reseteo la agendaGlobal
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.clear();

            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
            AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
         //   resultado[] = (Integer)(Math.random()*(3))+1;// numero = (int) (Math.random() *6) + 1; para un dado 

          //  mProgress.setMessage("Resultado Int:" + resultado);

           // resultado = (Integer) resultado;  // convierto a entero me aseguro
             Thread.sleep(3000);

            //mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea finalizada");

           //SystemClock.sleep(1000);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea finalizada");
    return null;
    }


@Override
protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCancelled(null);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea finalizada");

    try {
        Thread.sleep (3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mProgress.dismiss();
    /*if(mProgress != null){
        mProgress.dismiss();
        }*/
    //Aqui es donde devolvemos los datos a donde nos llama
    mCallback.onAcabeInicializacion(5);
    super.onPostExecute(null);
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//mProgress.setMessage( values[0]);
    //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

Comment: PLease show how you are executing this task

Comment: Im calling this from my mainactivity: new ServicioInicial(MainActivity.this).execute();

Answer (score 1):

When you're on doInBackgroundMethod you are working on a Thread apart from the UI thread so you can't just make anything to update your visual interface from there. So, there's no way to change it on doInBackground.

Instead, you can use OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute to deal with your progress. For what I think you're trying to it would be something like:

```
private Context mContext;

ProgressDialog mProgress;
private ServicioInicialFinalizado mCallback;

public ServicioInicial( Context context) {
    this.mContext=context;
    this.mCallback= ( ServicioInicialFinalizado) context;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
   mProgress= new ProgressDialog(mContext);
   mProgress.setMessage("Cargando contactos...Por favor espere");
mProgress.show();

mProgress.setMessage("Tarea comenzada");

}




@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... resultado) {


    try 
   {
       //Aqui simulo un calculo supercomplicado y lo ralentizamos  a 500 ms por numero




        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego   Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
     //   resultado[] = (Integer)(Math.random()*(3))+1;// numero = (int) (Math.random() *6) + 1; para un dado 

      //  mProgress.setMessage("Resultado Int:" + resultado);

       // resultado = (Integer) resultado;  // convierto a entero me aseguro
        Thread.sleep(200);

        //mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea finalizada");

       SystemClock.sleep(1000);


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

// mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea finalizada");
return null;
}



@Override
protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCancelled(null);
}


protected void onPostExecute() {

   mProgress.setMessage ("Result Integer en postexecute:");
     mProgress.setMessage ("Tarea terminada");
   try {

 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 mProgress.dismiss();

//Aqui es donde devolvemos los datos a donde nos llama
mCallback.onAcabeInicializacion(5);
super.onPostExecute(null);
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //  mProgress.setMessage( values[0]);
   //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

If your mProgress is not updating in the method onPostExecute, that's because your doInBackground is not finishing doing it's work, so take a look at that point, could be sth with your sleepers.

Comment: Calling `Thread.sleep()` from `OnPostExecute` will only block the UI, which can cause ANR(Application Not Responding).

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `AsyncTask <Void, String, Void>` and use `OnProgressUpdate` to update the messages.

Make these changes in your class:

```
class ServicioInicial extends AsyncTask <Void, String, Void> {

private Context mContext;

ProgressDialog mProgress;
private ServicioInicialFinalizado mCallback;

public ServicioInicial( Context context) {
this.mContext=context;
this.mCallback= (ServicioInicialFinalizado) context;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
mProgress= new ProgressDialog(mContext);
mProgress.setMessage("Cargando contactos...Por favor espere");
mProgress.show();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... resultado) {

try 
{
    Thread.sleep(2000);

        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.aguila));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Daniel", "c/ Diego Madrazo","92458", "daniel@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.caballo));
        AgendaGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.add(new contactoAgenda("Eduardo", "c/ Segovia","92458", "eduardo@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, true,"Familia", R.drawable.camaleon));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

  publishProgress("Tarea inicializada");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

publishProgress("Tarea finalizada");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

if(mProgress != null){
mProgress.dismiss
}

mCallback.onAcabeInicializacion(5);
super.onPostExecute(result);
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
mProgress.setMessage(values[0]);
super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

and run your app again.

**EDIT:**

To clear the `ArrayList` add this to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  miAgenda.clear();  //Clear ArrayList
}
```

Comment: Thanks...now it seems it does doinBackground... i load the contacts..But  now i cant set messages of begining task and finishing task. Now it gets stuck with the message "Cargando datos" and doesnt say anything else or dismiss to return to the mainactivity....

Comment: You can only set messages in `OnPreExecute` and `OnPostExecute`.

Comment: Now i have done it...i had comment the setmessage you told me... and then after loading contacts ( what now it does), it should enter in post execute and setmessage and dismiss... but it doeesnt...

Comment: Its better now but i have two problems: 1 - The messages run very quickly so i cant read them...I have deleted all the system clock and threads.sleep .... And the other problem im facing now is that im exiting the app and enter again and the contacts are growing... seems the arraylist miagenda is not empty when i run the app again...

Comment: I've made a few edits to my post. Make these changes in your class.

Comment: I updated the question with the progress made till now... Can you take a look...Ive done the clear arraylist...which i shouldnt because arraylist dont remain in memory when exiting...but just in case.. The problem is that i cannot stand the dialog for a time, like Toast for example..

Comment: I've made a few changes to the ServicioInicial class. Now you should be able to update the messages. Take a look at the updated post.

Comment: Max59 works perfect...thanks mate... i have i little problem now with arraylist... as is a initial service i clear the arraylist...i called this service from oncreate... but when i return from others activities to this activity...it begins in oncreate and then every time clears the playlist..in theory when you return from another activity, this has to begin with onresume or on start not in on create....Dont know if i had to open another thread

Comment: I think you should clear the arraylist in `onStop()` of your activity. That way, the arraylist would be cleared everytime you exit the app. Look at the edited post and try that.

Comment: It doeesnt work..i have in the activity a listview with all the members of miAgenda ( all the contacts). If i return to the activity i got and error and app closes because i click on a listview which is empty. Should be in onDestroy or onStart ( perhaps if you have an onstart function then it doesnt create it again the layout and all... i need one initialization process

Comment: You should probably ask another question for that.